# Using Logstash with MySQL and Elasticsearch, unable to send data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to send data to ES from a MySQL server using logstash. I am using ES 6.3.0 and Logstash 6.3.0. My config file looks as follows:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/Users/.../mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://..."
        jdbc_user => "user"
        jdbc_password => "****"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM user.customer"
    }
}
output {
    #stdout { codec => json_lines }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "customers"
    }
}
```

I am using a MySQL database with one table which has several columns of different data types. When I try to send data to ES I get the following error message:

```
[2018-07-03T14:39:06,088][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"customers", :_type=>"doc", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x2ff3608c>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"customers", "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"p-MnYGQBzIWWUpovTpES", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"mapper [uc_score] cannot be changed from type [long] to [float]"}}}}
```

After doing some research I came across that you cannot use different types in ES any longer, I am not however sure exactly what they mean. What can I do to pass this problem? What is a smart way of sending data from a MySQL database to ES? I am planning on using ES to analyze and visualize the data in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the limited ability to convert types using the JDBC driver.

Field `uc_score` has MySQL type `long` thas is not automatically converted by JDBC in elasticsearch type `float`. So you should add this fragment to the logstash pipeline configuration in `filter` section to convert `uc_score` field:

```
filter {
    mutate { convert => {"uc_score" => "float"} }
}
```

Do not forget to restart your logstash instance!

Source: [Importing Data from MySQL to Elasticsearch to Visualize it with Kibana](http://datascience-enthusiast.com/Miscellaneous/MySQL_to_ELK.html)